# Filter grayscale in chrome is buggy with :not selector

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css, svg-filters

i've got sth like that

```
$('body > :not(.extras)').addClass("desaturation_filtr");
```

and that must have apply this class to whole body without extras class

```
.desaturation_filtr
 {

    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

But when it does the website is quite buggy because webpage is pixelised and not readable

You can see it live @ http://www.industrukt.pl/des by clicking striped button on top right corner.

In Firefox all is good.

Tried to use

> $('.extras').removeClass("desaturation_filtr");

but it doesn't work. Of course before that line of code I removed not from previous snippet

I think this is Chrome bug :/ But don't know how to fix that

Comment: This works just fine in Chrome 25/Windows